# if Sum Exceeds show new record with the values left in next line

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
 A   B C  D    
12426 4 1 KT1217V
12426 4 1 KT1218V
12428 3 1 KT1217V
12428 3 1 KT1218V
12430 3 1 KT1217V
12430 3 1 KT1218V
12431 3 1 KT1217V
12431 3 1 KT1218V
12434 3 1 KT1217V
12434 3 1 KT1218V
12439 8 1 KT1217V
12439 8 1 KT1218V
12440 1 1 KT1217V
12440 1 1 KT1218V
12442 8 1 KT1217V
12442 8 1 KT1218V
12443 8 1 KT1217V
12443 8 1 KT1218V
```

I am looking for a result like this:

```
KT1217V      12426,12428 ..... 
KT1218       12426,12428,12431
KT1218       12434,12439
```

till value of column b sums < 5 if sum exceeds > 5
show new record of same with the values left 
where c=1

I wrote the query to obtain value < or > sum(column B) but unable to show new record of the same with leftover values column A for column D

```
select D,
(select a.A+',' from table1 a where a.D = b.D for XML PATH ('') )
from table1 b
WHERE c = 1
group by D
HAVING SUM(B)<5
ORDER BY D
```

Comment: Please show your own efforts. This is not a "write my code for me" website.

Comment: you can achieve this by using cursor : read row by row and insert into temp table and than show that table...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LISTAGG(), smth like SELECT A, LISTAGG(D, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D). There is no such things in Oracle as a.A+',' or for XML PATH ('')...

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I though query is for Oracle... Please tag your question-add sql server tag.